# Sort function for array of structures

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure

I have a structure called rain. It is defines like this

```
 struct Rain{
    string month;
    string year;
    double rainfall;
 }
```

I have an array of these (rain [240]) and I would like to sort using the sort algorithm. This is what I tried:

```
sort(rain.rainfall, rain.rainfall + 240);
```

but I get:

```
member reference base type 'Rainfall_data [240]' is not a structure or union
    sort(rain.rainfall, rain.rainfall + 240);
         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

I am just wondering if it is possible to use the sort algorithm this way, and if so what have I done wrong that it is not working?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the error message is not consistent with the name of the struct. Is your real struct called `Rainfall_data` ?

Comment: The argument to `sort` must be an array. `rain.rainfall` isn't an array. The array is just `rain`. If you want to sort by rainfall you have to provide a comparison function that compares that member of two structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often it's most convenient to embed the function into the class/struct:

```
struct Rain {
    string month;
    string year;
    double rainfall;
    bool operator < (const Rain& r1) const {
        return (rainfall < r1.rainfall);
    }
};
```

Now they can be sorted like the basic types:

```
std::sort(rain, rain + 240);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a comparison function that you can pass to `sort`, that knows how to compare two different `Rain` objects.

```
bool RainLess(const Rain &r1, const Rain &r2)
{
    return r1.rainfall < r2.rainfall;
}

std::sort(rain, rain+240, RainLess);
```

Comment: hmm, in the past ive only used two parameters in the sort function. Can you explain a bit to me the purpose of the third parameter and what it does? Thank you Mark

Comment: @Elchapo the third parameter always exists, but it defaults to `std::less` which uses `operator<` to compare the two objects. It should return `true` if the first argument is considered to be less than the second.

Comment: thank you! that makes a bit more sense, you've put me on the right track. Have a nice day